# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AMSPractice.Models.AddTable'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to asp.net and i am stuck on that code i cant resolve this error
"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AMSPractice.Models.AddTable', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AMSPractice.Models.AddTable]'."

I want to show only one value for example in my table there is more than one values name "first" so i want to show only one time "first" so when we write 
FirstOrDefault then give error and when we write Where then error is not shown
but i want back only one value where return more then one values.

Here is my code
Controller

```
public ActionResult Login(string Name,string TeacherID)
        {
            AdmissionDBEntities obj = new AdmissionDBEntities();
            AddTable t = new AddTable();
            var v = obj.AddTables.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Teacher.Equals(Name) && a.Teacher_Id.Equals(TeacherID));
            if (v != null)
            {
               **var var = obj.AddTables.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Teacher==Name);**
                return View(var);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("/Home/Index");
```

and  my View is:

```
@model IEnumerable<AMSPractice.Models.AddTable>
<h3>Classes Assigned</h3>
        <br /><br />
        <ul>
@foreach (var a in Model)
{ 
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(a.Class,"Sections","Attendance", new { nid = a.Foreign_Id }, null)
    </li>
}
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is from the way you have strongly typed your view. From your controller, when you return `return View(var);` you are passing a single object to your view, yet your view is strongly typed to expect an IEnumerable of the `AddTable` object.

You either need to return an IEnumerable from your controller, or change your view to expect only a single object.

Try the following to change your view to expect only a single object.

In your view change your strongly typed @model from what you have to `@model AMSPractice.Models.AddTable`

At that point, you wouldn't need the foreach and you would just have the following.

```
<li>
    @Html.ActionLink(a.Class,"Sections","Attendance", new { nid = Model.Foreign_Id}, null)
</li>
```

Comment: sorry bro i forgot to told that i want to show only unique values(means if "first" cames more than one time then show only one time). So i need foreach. but my issue is not resolved :\ .